# How to optimize Blender - Settings?

Tags: performance, settings

So, I upgraded my computer and now it is working much better. Still, I wonder if there is any document that explain how to best optimize it to match the computer.

For example, I was working on a sculpting with an image with about 9M faces. The system started to crawl at times, so I monitored my system capacity and,

1. GPU not very utilized with a top of about 27% usage.
2. CPU very lightly used (12700K)
3. Ram, still plenty available. 32GB Ram total, 70% top used
4. Using M2 SSD for scratch disk. Also seems low used.

I am trying to understand if the system was ok in capacity what is causing blender to slow down heavily at times.

I am not yet at rendering. Working sculpting on viewport shading.
Blender 3.21
Windows 11
Prefernces > System > OptiX (as using RTX GPU)

Thanks

Comment: Blender keeps several "copies" of your file on hand for the purposes of "undo" steps - the amount (default 32) can be changed under Preferences > System. Lowering the number may make things like sculpting more responsive, but this does affect how many times undo (`Ctrl+Z`) can be used so don't go too low.

Answer (score 2):

You can hide parts of your scene/object that you are not working with at that moment by using collections, local view(<kbd>/</kbd>) or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> in "Solid" viewport shading mode.

Also some operations in Blender might be done with only one CPU core, so it may(or may not) speed things up while modelling or sculpting if you disable Intel's Hyperthreading(in UEFI), but that will slow down rendering a bit. You may want to test if it makes a difference and if you care about it.

Generally this kind of optimizing should not matter. Working smart and not having unnecessary mess in your scenes and models is usually way more useful than trying to optimize hardware or software performance as it may improve speed of your work a couple of times as opposed to a couple of percent.

Other than that, there are no specific steps you should really take to optimize your PC for Blender or Blender for your PC. Modern operating systems take care of everything well. You might want not to run too many apps and programs in the background, scan your PC for viruses and malware from time to time.